# Getting error to normalize nested list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a nested list with dictionary. The following is just first element of the list

```
    {'id': 'abcde',
     'authorization': None,
     'operation_type': 'xx',
     'method': 'card',
     'transaction_type': 'asd',
     'card': {'type': 'dd',
      'brand': 'vv',
      'address': {'line1': 'xxxxxxx',
       'line2': '',
       'line3': '',
       'state': 'xx',
       'city': 'xxx',
       'postal_code': '12345',
       'country_code': 'xx'},
      'card_number': '123456XXXXXX7890',
      'holder_name': 'name user,
      'expiration_year': '20',
      'expiration_month': '02',
      'allows_charges': True,
      'allows_payouts': True,
      'bank_name': 'abc bank',
      'bank_code': '000'},
     'status': 'fgh',
     'conciliated': True,
     'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
     'operation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
     'description': 'asdmdefdsa',
     'error_message': 'sdaskjflj',
     'order_id': 'ashdgjasdfhk',
     'amount': 418.0,
     'customer': {'name': 'abc',
      'last_name': 'xyz',
      'email': 'abcdef@hotmail.com',
      'phone_number': '12345678',
      'address': None,
      'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:18-05:00',
      'external_id': None,
      'clabe': None},
     'fee': {'amount': 0.56, 'tax': 0.91, 'currency': 'XXX'},
     'currency': 'XXX'},
{'id': 'abcde',
     'authorization': None,
     'operation_type': 'xx',
     'method': 'card',
     'transaction_type': 'asd',
     'card': {'type': 'dd',
      'brand': 'vv',
      'address': {'line1': 'xxxxxxx',
       'line2': '',
       'line3': '',
       'state': 'xx',
       'city': 'xxx',
       'postal_code': '12345',
       'country_code': 'xx'},
      'card_number': '123456XXXXXX7890',
      'holder_name': 'name user,
      'expiration_year': '20',
      'expiration_month': '02',
      'allows_charges': True,
      'allows_payouts': True,
      'bank_name': 'abc bank',
      'bank_code': '000'},
     'status': 'fgh',
     'conciliated': True,
     'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
     'operation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
     'description': 'asdmdefdsa',
     'error_message': 'sdaskjflj',
     'order_id': 'ashdgjasdfhk',
     'amount': 418.0,
     'customer': {'name': 'abc',
      'last_name': 'xyz',
      'email': 'abcdef@hotmail.com',
      'phone_number': '12345678',
      'address': None,
      'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:18-05:00',
      'external_id': None,
      'clabe': None},
     'fee': {'amount': 0.56, 'tax': 0.91, 'currency': 'XXX'},
     'currency': 'XXX'}
```

I want to normalize the data to dataframe. I wrote the code as: json_normalize(d). But I am getting following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df = json_normalize(data)
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py in
>   json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix,
>   errors, sep)
>       201             # TODO: handle record value which are lists, at least error
>       202             #       reasonably
>   --> 203             data = nested_to_record(data, sep=sep)
>       204         return DataFrame(data)
>       205     elif not isinstance(record_path, list):
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py in
>   nested_to_record(ds, prefix, sep, level)
>        86             else:
>        87                 v = new_d.pop(k)
>   ---> 88                 new_d.update(nested_to_record(v, newkey, sep, level + 1))
>        89         new_ds.append(new_d)
>        90
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py in
>   nested_to_record(ds, prefix, sep, level)
>        82                     new_d[newkey] = v
>        83                 if v is None:  # pop the key if the value is None
>   ---> 84                     new_d.pop(k)
>        85                 continue
>        86             else:
>
> KeyError: 'address'

I understood that because address in None, the code is giving me error. But I don't know how to fix it. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
(Please note that the data is dummy data)

Answer (score 5):

The dictionary is badly formatted. First of all, you have lines like the following:

```
'holder_name': 'name user,
```

where the value `'name user` is not a valid string, since it's not enclosed by a single quote character on the right.

Second, in your code you have two elements of a list, that is, two dictionaries, each of them starting with `{'id': ...`, as opposed to a single element as claimed.

After fixing the values of `'holder_name` in both dictionaries and making it  a two-member list, you can proceed with using `json_normalize` and you would get an output like the following (with printed in stdout):

```
   amount authorization card.address.city card.address.country_code    ...        operation_type      order_id status transaction_type 0  
418.0          None               xxx                        xx       ...                    xx  ashdgjasdfhk    fgh              asd 1  
418.0          None               xxx                        xx       ...                    xx  ashdgjasdfhk    fgh              asd

[2 rows x 42 columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce this error but I couldn't. After creating a python3 venv and installing pandas with pip I copied your code (python dictionary and not json - my mistake, thanks @AlessandroCosentino +1 from me) to an editor and found out that lines 16 and 56 are missing a single quote 
`'holder_name': 'name user,`
 and should be 
`'holder_name': 'name user',`

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = {'id': 'abcde',
        'authorization': None,
        'operation_type': 'xx',
        'method': 'card',
        'transaction_type': 'asd',
        'card': {'type': 'dd',
        'brand': 'vv',
        'address': {'line1': 'xxxxxxx',
        'line2': '',
        'line3': '',
        'state': 'xx',
        'city': 'xxx',
        'postal_code': '12345',
        'country_code': 'xx'},
        'card_number': '123456XXXXXX7890',
        'holder_name': 'name user',
        'expiration_year': '20',
        'expiration_month': '02',
        'allows_charges': True,
        'allows_payouts': True,
        'bank_name': 'abc bank',
        'bank_code': '000'},
        'status': 'fgh',
        'conciliated': True,
        'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
        'operation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
        'description': 'asdmdefdsa',
 'error_message': 'sdaskjflj',
 'order_id': 'ashdgjasdfhk',
 'amount': 418.0,
 'customer': {'name': 'abc',
  'last_name': 'xyz',
  'email': 'abcdef@hotmail.com',
  'phone_number': '12345678',
  'address': None,
  'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:18-05:00',
  'external_id': None,
  'clabe': None},
 'fee': {'amount': 0.56, 'tax': 0.91, 'currency': 'XXX'},
 'currency': 'XXX'},
  {'id': 'abcde',
 'authorization': None,
 'operation_type': 'xx',
 'method': 'card',
 'transaction_type': 'asd',
 'card': {'type': 'dd',
  'brand': 'vv',
  'address': {'line1': 'xxxxxxx',
   'line2': '',
   'line3': '',
   'state': 'xx',
   'city': 'xxx',
   'postal_code': '12345',
   'country_code': 'xx'},
  'card_number': '123456XXXXXX7890',
  'holder_name': 'name user',
  'expiration_year': '20',
  'expiration_month': '02',
  'allows_charges': True,
  'allows_payouts': True,
  'bank_name': 'abc bank',
  'bank_code': '000'},
 'status': 'fgh',
 'conciliated': True,
 'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
 'operation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:17-05:00',
 'description': 'asdmdefdsa',
 'error_message': 'sdaskjflj',
 'order_id': 'ashdgjasdfhk',
 'amount': 418.0,
 'customer': {'name': 'abc',
  'last_name': 'xyz',
  'email': 'abcdef@hotmail.com',
  'phone_number': '12345678',
  'address': None,
  'creation_date': '2018-09-23T23:58:18-05:00',
  'external_id': None,
  'clabe': None},
 'fee': {'amount': 0.56, 'tax': 0.91, 'currency': 'XXX'},
 'currency': 'XXX'}


print(json_normalize(data))
```

the output is this
[image: a screenshot from my term]

This could easily be avoided by using a smart editor - eg SublimeText - with python highlighting. What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: Try using a JSON Formatter & Validator - https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: @NikolaosDalezios a JSON string is different from a Python dictionary and a JSON formatter doesn't help here (for example, Python uses None objects, JSON uses null). What OP needs here is an editor that supports Python syntax, not a JSON validator.

Comment: You're right @AlessandroCosentino, but in this case the problem I think was a badly formatted JSON string and not the None or Null value - a common syntax error.

Comment: @NikolaosDalezios None/Null was just an example. What I meant is that here we are talking about Python syntax, not JSON syntax.